# RIGHT, LEFT and CHARINDEX not performing as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, charindex

I am trying to reorder a column of names that is in the form *lastname, firstname* to *firstname lastname*.  The original column is NAME_BAT and I have confirmed there are no leading or trailing spaces.  Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT TOP (100) NAME_BAT
    , LTRIM(RIGHT(NAME_BAT, CHARINDEX(', ', NAME_BAT) - 1)) AS FIRST_NAME
    , RTRIM(LEFT(NAME_BAT, CHARINDEX(', ', NAME_BAT) - 1)) AS LAST_NAME
    , LTRIM(RIGHT(NAME_BAT, CHARINDEX(', ', NAME_BAT) - 1)) + ' ' + RTRIM(LEFT(NAME_BAT, CHARINDEX(', ', NAME_BAT) - 1)) AS NAME_FULL
FROM pitch_aggregate
;
```

and here is a screenshot of the output:

[Output from SQL query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QahR.png)

Why are the first four rows perfect, then row 5 includes a leading comma and space before the name, and in row 8 the first name has the first two letter cut off?

Comment: Without seeing the data, that's impossible to know. Can you create a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) which demonstrates the results

Comment: [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Forgive the newbie mistakes.  I'm using SSMS.  Let me see if I can do a DBFiddle as requested...

Comment: Because you're counting from the left to find the match and then using that same number as an index to strip off characters from the right. It's coincidence that it works sometimes because the halves have the same lengths.

Comment: Just use like `substring(str, n, 100)` to grab everything from n forward.

Comment: What is the source of the data? Can you have them fix it so they stop jamming two different pieces of data into a single column in a format you don't want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take

`LTRIM(RIGHT(NAME_BAT, CHARINDEX(', ', NAME_BAT) - 1)) AS FIRST_NAME`

Presume data like `Casanova, Bob`

`CHARINDEX(', ', NAME_BAT)` returns 9

`RIGHT(NAME_BAT, CHARINDEX(', ', NAME_BAT) - 1)` is the rightmost 9-1 = 8 characters, which is `nova, Bob`

(All your sample/testing firs and last names are nearly the same length.) I'm guessing this is not what you really want?

Now, something like

`SUBSTRING(NAME_BAT, CHARINDEX(', ', NAME_BAT) + 2, 100)`

might be what you're looking for. Me, I see it as a prime example of why SQL is a poor place to implement string manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your query and you do indeed have some formatting issues.

Rather than pick it apart, here is a simpler working alternative you can try. By using `cross apply` and a `values` construct you can abstract out the string splitting to leave a more easy to use `select` list of columns.

```
select name_bat, f.name FirstName, l.name LastName, Concat_ws(' ',f.name,l.name) Name_full
from t
cross apply (values( Left(name_bat,CharIndex(',',name_bat)-1 )))l(name)
cross apply (values( Replace(name_bat,Concat(l.name,', '),'') ))f(name)
```

[See original and new version example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6132f57c2cc909d44492cd4782fe179b)